# Clistview clicked item pass to other activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I want to pass my Listview clicked item ID to other activity using intent. HoW could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You get the id and add it to the [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) as an Extra using the respective (long) [putExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20long%5B%5D)), with a suitable key (first parameter).

In the other Activity you get the Intent and then get the value from the Extra using the [getLongExtra](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20long%5B%5D)) using the same key (first parameter) noting that the default value should be a value (e.g. -1) that will not be an id.

## Working Example

The following is a working example :-

### The Database Helper DBOpenHelper.java

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "notes.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TBL_NOTE = "note_table";
    public static final String COL_NOTE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_NOTE_TEXT = "note_text";

    private final String create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_NOTE + "(" +
            COL_NOTE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_NOTE_TEXT + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    private static final String drop_table = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_NOTE;

    public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int version_old, int version_new) { }

    public long addNote(String note) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NOTE_TEXT",note);
        return db.insert("note_table",null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllNotes() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TBL_NOTE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- An instantiated instance of this is used to :

  - open the database (in the example it is named **notes.db**), it will create the database if it doesn't exist.
  - add data via the **addNote** method.
  - return a Cursor containing all the Notes via the **getAllNotes** method.

### The initial activity MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter MSCA;
    private Cursor mCsr;
    private DBOpenHelper mDBHelper;

    public static final String INTENTEXTRAKEY_NOTE_ID = "iek_noteid";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DBOpenHelper(this);
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        addSomeTestData(); //Adds a row every time the App is run (for testing)
        ViewData();
    }

    private void ViewData(){

        mCsr = mDBHelper.getAllNotes();
        if (MSCA == null) {
            MSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mCsr,
                    new String[]{DBOpenHelper.COL_NOTE_TEXT},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0);
            mListView.setAdapter(MSCA);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(INTENTEXTRAKEY_NOTE_ID,id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else {
            MSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }

    private void addSomeTestData() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase(),DBOpenHelper.TBL_NOTE) < 1) {
            mDBHelper.addNote("My Note");
            mDBHelper.addNote("Another Note");
            mDBHelper.addNote("Yet Another Note");
            mDBHelper.addNote("And so on.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCsr.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ViewData();
    }
}
```

- This activity :-

  - Adds some notes to the database (if none already exist)
  - Lists all of the notes in the database
  - sets a onItemClickListener to call the activity **OtherActivity** passing the **id** via an IntenExtra.
- Notes

  - A CursorAdpater (SimpleCursorAdapter) in this case is ideally suited as the **id** is passed to the **onItemClick** method by the listener. **NOTE** this requires a column, named specifically **_id** (as per **BaseColumns._ID**) and that the column is an alias of the **rowid** column.
  - The **onDestroy** method has been overridden to close the Cursor when done with it (i.e. when the Activity is detsroyed). This isn't so important in the initial actiivty as it's lifetime would typically be for the entire App (closing the Cursor in hierarchically lower Activities is more important).
  - The ViewData method manages a single instance of the adapter (i.e. creating it only when it hasn't been instantiated) and also refreshing of the ListView. Hence why it is called in the overridden **onResume** method. i.e. another activity may add. delete or update the database so the ListView will updated upon return.

### The activity called from the initial activity OtherActivity.java

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mNoteId;
    Button mDone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
        mNoteId = this.findViewById(R.id.noteid);
        mDone = this.findViewById(R.id.done);
        mDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        long id = i.getLongExtra(MainActivity.INTENTEXTRAKEY_NOTE_ID,-1);
        mNoteId.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

- This activity :-

  - sets the onClickListener of the button to return to the calling/invoking activity.
  - extracts the **id** from the Intent Extras passed to the activity from the calling activity and sets the **noteid** TextView with the extracted value (the passed **id**).

## Result

### Initially :-

[image]

### Clicking Yet Another Note :-

[image]

- As **Yet Another Note** was the third note added it's **id** is **3**.

Comment: Kindly tell me that same Method is applied in the case of pass id from listview to listview ?